# getting (InvalidArgument) when calling the PutObject operation: None

Tags: python-3.x, django, amazon-s3, boto3

I was trying to upload profile image to `AWS S3`. My role simulates having `AWSS3FullAccess Policy` attached and using `boto3 client`.

I don't know why i am getting this error. I have wrote `CORS Permissions` to my bucket and allowing `* hosts`.

I would be glad if you help me find and solve the problem.

Comment: Please, share your sample codes.

Comment: thank You for the response,Hamed. It was getting because of ACL type. I have corrected it.

Comment: Please can you solve that for others in the future. Here is the link.     https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71821254/invalidargument-when-calling-the-putobject-operation-none

Answer (score 1):

I was putting `public_read` for the ACL instead of `public-read`.

i.e., invalid ACL value.

Appears that OP had the same issue, as noted in the comments.